# Can Access data of associated model in console but not in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, output, associations

In my app i have two types of users: `students` and `companies`.
During the registration process, i manage with the wicked gem, the user is asked to fill in data depending on the accounttype (student or company) he chose. 
For example, a student have to fill in his university, a company have to fill in the amount of employers.
When the registration process is finished, everything is fine, but somehow i cant access the data of the user which chose accounttype 2 - company.
The data is stored in two seperated associated models:
For students: `accountinfo` (ye i know its against convention and should have the name account_info)
For companies: `accountinfos_company` (ye i know, weird pluralization .. but it does the trick and i am not confused by it)

Everything works fine for the students. I am able to fill in data and the data is properly saved within a nested form. Same goes for the companies but unfortunately i am not able to output the data of `accountinfos_company` in my app. What i can do is for example:

```
@user.accountinfo.description
```

For student-accounts. But if I try:

```
@user.accountinfos_company.description
```

The output fails with an error

```
undefined method `accountinfos_company' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc1851e6e20>
```

SOMEHOW I am able to output the data of the particular user via console like: `User.last.accountinfos_company.description`. I copied every step I made for the first associated model, the data gets properly saved but I am not able to access it inside the app.
I thought it might be something missing, some definition or sth like this but as far as i can see, everything is fine.

**users_controller.rb** (User association stuff gets created in another controller)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create( user_params )
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.not_complete?
      redirect_to user_steps_path
    else
      render 'show'
    end

  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # might be the right way?
    @user.update(user_params)
    if @user.update(user_params)
       redirect_to User.find(params[:id]), notice: 'Profil bearbeitet.'
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end


  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :accounttype, 
   :accountinfo, :accountinfos_company, :profile_image, :active, accountinfo_attributes:[:id], accountinfos_company_attributes:[:id])
  end

end
```

**user_steps_controller.rb**

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController

include Wicked::Wizard
steps :welcome, :info

before_action :authenticate_user!


def show
        @user = current_user
        render_wizard
end

def create
        @user = current_user
        if @user.accounttype == 1
          @accountinfo = @user.accountinfo.create(user_params)
        elsif @user.accounttype == 2
          @accountinfos_company = @user.accountinfos_company.create(user_params)
        end
end

def update
        @user = current_user
        @user.update(user_params)

        render_wizard @user
end


private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :accountinfo, :accountinfos_company,:profile_image, :active, accountinfo_attributes:[:id, :city, :competence, :description, :university], accountinfos_company_attributes:[:id, :city, :company_type, :description, :company_name, :employer_amount])
end

private
def redirect_to_finish_wizard_path
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Danke für deine Zeit!"
end

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :accountinfo
  has_one :accountinfos_company
  has_many :offer_posts
  has_many :search_posts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accountinfo, update_only: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accountinfos_company, update_only: true


  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :accounttype

end
```

**accountinfo.rb and accountinfos_company.rb**
`belongs_to :user`

I dont know if i have something missed but yeah.
If you could help me i would be really glad.

Comment: where exactly is this error coming from? What line of code? You are probably setting `@user` to something incorrect but I'm not seeing where from the code you're shown.

Comment: Thank you for sour response. Unfortunately i have no idea how i fixed it but the error is gone now :S